# Parse some information from dynamically created page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I work in [service-now ITSM tool](http://www.servicenow.com/solutions/service-management.html) and the URL is always the same: *example.service-now.com/navpage.do* it means, that content updates dynamically in the web page.
Here is the part of code from Incident's page:

```
    <tr id="element.u_incident_ict.number">
      <td id="label.u_incident_ict.number" title="" data-type="label" choice="0" class="label label_spacing" nowrap="true" type="string">
        <span id="status.u_incident_ict.number" class="read_only label_description" title="Security does not permit writing to this field" oclass="read_only" mandatory="false">&nbsp;</span>
        <label onclick="return labelClicked(this);" for="u_incident_ict.number" dir="ltr">Number:</label>
      </td>
      <td class="input_controls" nowrap="true">
        <input id="sys_original.u_incident_ict.number" value="ICT0169881" type="hidden" name="sys_original.u_incident_ict.number">
        <input id="sys_readonly.u_incident_ict.number" value="ICT0169881" class="disabled" style="direction:ltr; background-color:tomato; " readonly="readonly">
        <input id="u_incident_ict.number" value="ICT0169881" name="u_incident_ict.number" style="visibility: hidden; width: 1px;" onchange="onChange('u_incident_ict.number');">
      </td>
    </tr>
```

My final task is:
I want to write a javascript bookmarklet to parse information from open Incident's page and show it in a new tab of browser.

But first, I couldn't get the `value` of the last `<input>`. I tried the command:

```
document.getElementById("u_incident_ict.number")
```

in developer's console of Google Chrome, I receive the 'null' answer.

I tried with variable:

```
var x = document.getElementById("u_incident_ict.number")
x.value
```

But receive the error because of null:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

So, my question is:
How to parse information from this page with the help of javascript.

Comment: first you check the html which is correctly load or not

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine please check the code. Try to use JavaScript code after document ready, it might be possible you are accessing HTML element before load

Link to example > http://jsfiddle.net/nme8tcpn/

```
<span id="status.u_incident_ict.number" class="read_only label_description" title="Security does not permit writing to this field" oclass="read_only" mandatory="false">&nbsp;</span>

<label onclick="return labelClicked(this);" for="u_incident_ict.number" dir="ltr">Number:</label>

<input id="sys_original.u_incident_ict.number" value="ICT0169881" type="hidden" name="sys_original.u_incident_ict.number">

<input id="sys_readonly.u_incident_ict.number" value="ICT0169881" class="disabled" style="direction:ltr; background-color:tomato; " readonly="readonly">

<input id="u_incident_ict.number" value="ICT0169881" name="u_incident_ict.number" style="visibility: hidden; width: 1px;" onchange="onChange('u_incident_ict.number');">

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

var x = document.getElementById("u_incident_ict.number")
alert(x.value)
```

Comment: yes  it is working in js fiddle but he can not get value

Comment: @JDev, Yes, it works in jsfiddle but doesn't work on the webpage:
![Error message on webpage](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16465263/StackQuotes/jquery.png)